# What does `-k` stand for in `lightning-cli`?

Tags: core-lightning, invoices

I find it very convenient, one does not have to worry about the order of arguments, e.g.

```
lightning-cli -k invoice msatoshi=0.001btc label=label1 description="This is a description" expiry=45m
```

I would like to know the source of this acronym, what does **k** in `-k` stand for? Where can I read about it? I haven't found anything about it in `lightning-cli help`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually the first thing I got confused with after I installed my a lightning node for the very first time back in 2018. c-lightning ships with two (actually more) programs

1. `lightningd`
2. `lighthning-cli`

`lightning-cli` is a command line tool that sends commands via JSON RPC over a unix domain socket to `lightningd` so if you type: `lightning-cli help` what actually happens is that you send the `help` command to `lightningd` this will give you a list of all commands that `lightningd` can accept.

This is different to the command line arguments that can be given to `lightning-cli` which you are asking about. You can get the command line arguments by typing in `lightning-cli --help`. My output looks like this:

```
lightning-cli --help
Usage: lightning-cli <command> [<params>...]
--conf=<file>             Specify configuration file
--lightning-dir=<dir>     Set base directory: network-specific subdirectory is
                          under here (default: "/home/user/.lightning")
--network <arg>           Select the network parameters (bitcoin, testnet,
                          signet, regtest, litecoin or litecoin-testnet)
                           (default: bitcoin)
--mainnet                 Alias for --network=bitcoin
--testnet                 Alias for --network=testnet
--signet                  Alias for --network=signet
--allow-deprecated-apis <arg>
                          Enable deprecated options, JSONRPC commands, fields,
                          etc. (default: true)
--rpc-file <arg>          Set JSON-RPC socket (or /dev/tty)
                           (default: "lightning-rpc")
--help|-h                 Show this message. Use the command help (without
                          hyphens -- "lightning-cli help") to get a list of all
                          RPC commands
-H|--human-readable       Human-readable output
-F|--flat                 Flatten output ('x.y.x=' format)
-J|--json                 JSON output (default unless 'help')
-R|--raw                  Raw, unformatted JSON output
-k|--keywords             Use format key=value for <params>
-o|--order                Use params in order for <params>
-N|--notifications <arg>  Set notification level, or none (default: info)
--version|-V              Print version and exit
```

From there you can see that the `-k` argument stands for `keywords`

> `-k|--keywords             Use format key=value for <params>`

For completeness there is even the possibility to get the command line arguments for `lightningd` by typing `lightningd --help` which gives you basically all config arguments and additionally the plugin system can append command line options.